# How to disable Ajax Call from WooCommerce in a single checkout page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, woocommerce, checkout

I have two checkout pages in my website and want to disable WooCommerce Ajax calls just for one of them.
I tried adding this code to functions.php but it disables Ajax for all the checkout pages:

```html
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_woocommerce_cart_fragments', 11); function dequeue_woocommerce_cart_fragments() { if (is_front_page()) wp_dequeue_script('wc-cart-fragments'); } function disable_checkout_script(){ wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' ); } add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_checkout_script' );
```

How can I apply this code to just one checkout page with this ID : 6355?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is_page()` function, something like this -

```
function disable_checkout_script() {
  if ( is_page( 6355 ) ) {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' ); 
  } else {
    /** do other stuff */
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_checkout_script' );
```

Please refer to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/ for more information.

Comment: This didn't dequeue checkout js for some reason